# How can I install wayfire in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: compiz, compositing

I am facing a lot of trouble in trying to install [wayfire][1], which is a compositor for wayland inspired (or based, idk) in the old, old compiz.

The problem is that this application requires a LOT of dependencies and these dependencies have little to no documentation in how to install them (check the README on github), so I am asking help to see if there is any noble soul who could just show what are the commands that are necessary to install them.

For example, I don't have the slightest idea on how to install Pango or PangoCairo.

Also, you might be asking to yourself "Why would a person be interested in installing such a compositor in 2023 ?".

Well, my Calculus professor is almost blind, but he can see a little and he uses compiz in order to have accessibility to his desktop (he is also a programmer), but the problem is that he is still using ubuntu 16.04, since the more recent versions stopped using this compositor, so he asked my help to try to install some application similar to compiz to see if it works, I tried compiz-fusion, but didn't work, so my final hope is wayfire.

Any help will be appreciated. And the repo of wayfire is [here](https://github.com/WayfireWM/wayfire)

Answer (score 0):

wayfire is available as `sudo apt install wayfire` from the default repositories in Ubuntu 22.10 and later.

EDIT: these may also help:

- http://blog.northfield.ws/wayfire-ubuntu-packages/
- https://github.com/peux-os-sic/Peux-wayfire-22